# What is the name for 'curdling' of coffee by milk?

Tags: single-word-requests

I can't drink black coffee (except on ice).

Unless I add milk to it so it thickens it is unpalatable to me. It resembles curdling but is some kind of suspension.

What is the word for such a thickening?

Example: I add milk to my coffee to make it a palatable suspension.

Thanks as ever

Comment: I think that’s a ***colloidal suspension***.  (Coffee is a solution but milk is a suspension)

Comment: Hi, jtlz2: I provided an answer to your question yesterday. Let me know what you think. Thanks. Don (rhetorician)

Comment: Stack Exchange has a discussion board for food, Seasoned Advice. If you're interested in what happens to coffee or what the culinary terminology is, you should ask there. There is also a board for chemistry questions if you want a more technical answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The one word you are looking for is [flocculation](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/flocculation).

Here is a quasi-scientic--but helpful--explanation about what happens when you add milk to your iced coffee:

> [Curdling Chemical Reaction](https://sciencenotes.org/why-milk-curdles/)
>
> Fresh milk is an example of a colloid, consisting of fat and protein
> particles floating in a water-based solution. The colloidal suspension
> scatters light, causing milk to appear white. The protein molecules,
> mainly casein, repel each other so they naturally distribute evenly
> through the liquid. Milk is slightly acidic. When the pH is lowered
> even more by the addition of another acidic ingredient ***[such as coffee]***, the protein
> molecules stop repelling each other. This allows them to stick
> together or coagulate into the clumps known as curds. The watery
> liquid that remains is called whey.

The jist is that when two acidic liquids combine, there is curdling, or *flocculation*.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what phenomenon you're trying to find the word for. A mixture of coffee and milk may curdle, but you already know the word for that curdling (namely, "curdling"), so that can't be what you're asking about. And, in my experience, adding milk to coffee doesn't make the coffee thicker, so that part of your question doesn't make sense to me.

I'm guessing that you're asking how to describe the "creaminess" that milk lends to coffee. And it sounds like you're asking how to describe not the creamy flavor, but the feeling that it has in your mouth—the mouthfeel.

So, I think that I would express that by saying:

> I add milk to my coffee to give it a creamy mouthfeel.

That said, if I were talking about coffee and milk, I, personally, would probably just say something like:

> I like coffee mixed with milk.